# Renaming Window Variable

Tags: javascript

I have arrived at a situation where I need to rename a window variable because of conflict arising from some other library which cannot be renamed.

Now, that global instance is being used extensively throughout the app like at thousands of places. Renaming is an option but is not trustworthy enough and checking all instances is a pain in it self. Is there any simple way of doing this?

What can be the best way to avoid any errors?

Some of the classes are wrapped inside define block and using IIFE will not be possible with them.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly wrap the global instance in an IIFE so that the global instance is no longer global.

Simply something like

```
(function() {
    //Your code here
}());
```

would be sufficient

Comment: for now, i would not prefer that. this is being used across different files and this will be tough doing that, wrapping every possible class with this on top of requirejs. some classes do have requirejs while some dont. for non-require, this would work like a charm

Comment: If you are using requirejs why would you need window variables? You can define a module and then require them in another modules. http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defsimple

Comment: it's some legacy code which i have to live with and it's been like this and i cannot just change every bad thing about it in some time